# WP8 video streaming with Media Foundation

Tags: media-player, h.264, windows-phone-8, ms-media-foundation, sharpdx

I wish to streaming H264 video to Windows Phone 8 application. 
So how I can do it with ShardDX? (Or maybe native function from Media Foundation).

I found MediaEngine class for playing video, but I need "manually" parsing of frames and getting them to decoder or player, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Phone 8 we only support Microsoft's proprietary RTSP and HTTP streaming protocols. Unfortunately we don't support any other protocols like MPEG DASH or HLS at this time. The Smooth Streaming protocol is handled by the SS Platform SDK.

You can implement your own streaming protocol parser rather easily though. You can use the MediaStreamSource API to do this. You will be responsible for parsing the stream and pull out the MP4 samples though. There is a lot of open source parsing code out there and you should be able to find code for your protocol.

[MediaStreamSource Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.media.mediastreamsource(v=vs.105).aspx)

I hope this helps,

James

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested, this was released for 8.0/8.1 support: https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/MicrosoftHLSSDK